# How to send response from class object promise to controller in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I have a question.
I am using a NodeJS app divided in three main parts

1. Data access object
   Here, I created a function that make the direct interaction with the database only in this file.

   const { response } = require('express');
   const db = require('../connection/db.js');

   /* Export */
   module.exports = {
   // Insert User
   insertUser: (parameters) => {
   const sqlStatement = 'INSERT INTO users SET ?';
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   db.query(sqlStatement, parameters, (error, response) => {
   if (error) {
   return reject(error);
   }
   return resolve(response);
   })
   })
   }
   }
2. Object class
   In this class I will make the validation, and create the method with arguments, then implement the data access object `insertUser`.

   ```
    const db = require('../dataAccessObject/dao.js');
   ```

   class User {
   constructor (fname, lname, age, email, password, avatar, gender) {
   this.fname  =  fname;
   this.lname  =  lname;
   this.age  =  age;
   this.email  =  email;
   this.password  =  password;
   this.avatar  =  avatar;
   this.gender  =  gender;
   }

   ```
    /* Methods */
    createUser() {
        db.insertUser({
            'firstName'     : this.fname,
            'lastName'      : this.lname,
            'age'           : this.age,
            'email'         : this.email,
            'password'      : this.password,
            'userAvatar'    : this.avatar,
            'gender'        : this.gender
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log(this);
            return this;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.code == 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' && error.errno === 1062) throw new Error('This email is allready in use')
            else throw error;
        })
    }

    /* Validations */
   ```

   }

   module.exports = User;
3. Controller

   const newUser = new User("fname", "lname", 22, "ema2121il", "password", "avatar", "gender");
   newUser.createUser();
   res.send(newUser)

I need to find a way to pass the validations errors, or the duplicate error from the point 2 (Object class) to the controller.

Please how can I do this?

Comment: Currently, I cannot send the rejected response from the User class to the express response

Comment: the validation should be done in controller. i recommend `joi` library

Comment: Thanks. But what about the response from the promise?

Answer (score 1):

So, if your goal is to return data to the express controller (from the class). The best way is to utilize the Promise Library. So your `createUser` function should look like this:

```
 createUser() {
   return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>  {
       db.insertUser({
         'firstName'     : this.fname,
         'lastName'      : this.lname,
         'age'           : this.age,
         'email'         : this.email,
         'password'      : this.password,
         'userAvatar'    : this.avatar,
         'gender'        : this.gender
       })
       .then(() => {
         console.log(this);
         this.runValidations()
         return resolve(this);
     })
     .catch(error => {
         if (error.code == 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' && error.errno === 1062) {
            return reject('This email is already in use')
         } else {
            return reject();
          } 
     })
   });
 }
```

Then to utilize it from your controller, utilize async/await to utilize the method.

```
//The Controller Code

app.get('/create-user', async(req, res) =>  {
    const user = new User(req.body) // Assuming this is how you're instantiating class
    try {
       const newUser = await user.createUser();
       console.log("User is Created");
    } catch (err) {
       //Your Error will be available here.
       console.log("Your Error: ", err)
    }
    

})
```

This should get you what you need :)

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks aloooot. :)